# Minimal set of files required to build Android's bionic

Tags: android, build, bionic

I made some changes to Android's bionic in order to run it with a specific application. I'd like to keep these modifications in my source control (SVN). Any idea what the minimal set of files required to still be able to build bionic with Android's regular envsetup.sh->lunch->make workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got [ebuild scripts](https://github.com/krisk0/pc-linux-android) that build from source android-x86_64-targeting toolchain (including of course bionic).

To build bionic, my script **bionic-5.1.1-r29.ebuild** takes 6 .zip files from github.com (using SHA sums to get a fixed version). Those 6 files are contents of github repositories

```
android/platform_bionic
android/platform_build
pbatard/bootimg-tools
pstglia/device-generic-common
pstglia/device-generic-x86_64
llvm-mirror/compiler-rt
```

I am not sure if the choice is minimal, but the unpacked weight is less than 300M which is a lot smaller than a dozen gigabyte you-know-from-where.